# How to customize Typus Admin for Rails to use a a special form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm using the [Typus Admin UI](https://github.com/fesplugas/typus) for a Ruby on Rails project and it's great.
I was wondering if there's a way to customize it to do the following:

There is a database column named "account_type" which is an integer.
Some non-technical admins use the Admin site and aren't aware of
the integer to description mappings (e.g. 0 = START, 200 = READY, 400 = PENDING).

So I'd like to create a drop down box ( tag) whose values shows
START, READY, PENDING.  And when the form is submitted the "account_type" field
is correctly changed to (0, 200, or 400).

Does anyone know if this is possible with Typus and how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was documented here:
https://github.com/fesplugas/typus/wiki/customization-user-interface

I learned that views for the admin can be overrided by creating directories with the model name in the app/views/admin .  So to override views for a "Book" class you can

- Run "rails generate typus:views"
- create the directory app/views/admin/books
- copy files from app/views/admin/resources to the app/views/admin/books directory
- change files as needed (I changed the _form.html.erb)

Comment: Or you can place this inside your conroller action (f.e. 'edit'):
```add_resources_action 'typus.buttons.my_action_name', { action: :my_action_name }, { class: 'btn btn-default', data: {mykey: :myvalue}, confirmation: 'Are you sure?' }``` and ```super``` on the next line.
Controller should have 'my_action_name' action.